# Store data after parsing JSON

Tags: swift, xcode

I need some help regarding this code. I try to retrieve the data from the parsing but my array is empty. I miss something for sure but I can't find it...

When printing dataMovie the console shows: []
Same with dataMovie.count, get 0.

Thanks a lot.

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var dataMovie: [Movie] = []
   
    
    @IBOutlet var TrendingMovieCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var headImage: UIImageView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getTrendMovie()

        TrendingMovieCollectionView.delegate = self
        TrendingMovieCollectionView.dataSource = self
        

    }

    private func getTrendMovie() {
        FetchData.shared.getTrendingMovie { results in
            self.dataMovie = FetchData.shared.data

        }
    }  
}

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       
        return  dataMovie.count
       
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "TrendingMovieCell", for: indexPath) as! TrendingMovieCollectionViewCell
        let data = dataMovie[indexPath.item]

        let url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
        let link = url + (data.poster_path!)


        cell.moviePoster.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: link))
        

        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is the function `sd_setImage(with:)`? I gather thats from a 3rd party library? A quick search makes it look like it's from a library called sdwebimage. You should add that info to your question.

Comment: If you are using SDWebImage, you should be aware that it is an Objective-C library, and thus quite old. It looks like it's being maintained for now, but I wouldn't do new work using Objective-C libraries at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to change here in your code.
For starters you need to move the call to the URL out of the collection view.

Create a function that grabs the data first and stores it in an object.

When you have the data in an object, you can use that object to populate the collection view.

I would recommend looking at these tutorials here to help you out. There really is a-lot you need to change.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/3244963-urlsession-tutorial-getting-started

https://www.raywenderlich.com/18895088-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started